# What is the difference between evaluation metrics and features in relation to binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I'm having a hard time trying to separate these two concepts in my mind.

I know that evaluation metrics such as [BLEU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLEU) can be used to measure the quality of a given input against a reference (as in Machine Translation).  But can this score be leveraged into classifying sentences into two categories? For example, a sentence with a certain evaluation metric score above 0.50 would be given a 'yes' while everything below 0.50 given a 'no'.

Also, it this possibly related to features used in machine learning algorithms? For example, say the phrase, "in the past" is a possible feature of the data which then could be used to classify inputs into having this feature or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are completely missing the meaning of basic concepts here.

- evaluation metric is a function which given: some model/algorithm answers and some **golden standard** (true answers, provided by an expert) measures how good is your model/algorithm. It has nothing (ok, not nothing, as it is often used during cross-validation and tuning model's parameters) to do with the actual classification process. It is **not** used to make any decisions, it is a method of quantifing how good are your **results**.
- features are just data **representation**, so there are related in the sense, that they are part of the problem, and obiously correct choice of features (also called **feature engineering**) has a big impact on the quality of your model. But "a possible feature of the data which then could be used to classify inputs into having this feature or not" is rather meaningless. Feature is a value of some function, often called feature detector, lets call it `f`, which applied to your input object `x` returns some value, for example - number, or a 0/1 (there is not/there is) representation of some phenomen. For example such feature could be (for text documents) " does given text contain substring "in the past", and so `f("I like trains")=false (0)`, and `f("I liked trains in the past")=1 (true)`. You do not train classifier to detect features, you extract them using some simple (efficient) algorithm to represent your data, which is then used to classify them to some classes. Once you have `f` there would be no point in "classify inputs into having this feature", because `f` does **exactly** this. Of course it is possible to actually train classifiers for "filling in" missing features when they are not avaliable for some data points, but this is a more advanced topic, and it does not seem to be the part of your question.

I would recommend you to watch some great introduction videos into machine learning by Andrew Ng, avaliable on the coursera platform: https://class.coursera.org/ml/lecture/preview